# azure app service throttling?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, throttling

I'm facing an issue with my MVC app service deployed on Azure. 
My MVC action method receives requests and depening on parameters in querystring, it performs a redirect to external URLs.
The usual response time is milliseconds but sometimes there are requests that took a real higher response time:

[image]

The action method is real simple and there's not so much logic in it so it could be summarized as follows:

```
public ActionResult performRedirect(string id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("start");
        if (id == "1")
            return Redirect("http://URLA");
        else if (id == "2")
            return Redirect("http://URLB");
        else
            return Redirect("http://URLC");
    }
```

My application uses ApplicationInsights therefore i performed analysis on that and what i found is that whenever there are "slow" requests there's a sort of delay between the time the request is handled by the action method and the diagnostic tracking "start" (up to 10 seconds!).

My question is: why is this happening? is it because of an increase in the requests to the action that cannot be managed and therefore there's a incoming queue to be emptied? should i increase the performances of the resource (now i'm using a S1 with 2 instances)?

Answer (score 0):

To the performance issue, there is not a specific explanation. It may caused by several reasons, like bandwidth restrictions, source limited, etc.

You could try to troubleshoot with the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation). Also some ways to mitigate the issue,

1. [Scale the web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#scale-the-web-app)
2. [Use AutoHeal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#use-autoheal)
3. [Restart the web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#restart-the-web-app)

Besides, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026701/azure-long-response-time-bottleneck) is a similar issue, you could refer to it.