# Query times out on Azure but not from localhost on same db

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have a query that is timing out (command timeout is set to 600s for the shake of testing) when it is ran from Azure App Service. When I run the website locally from visual studio and connect to the exact same db as the App Service, the same query needs something between 9-11 seconds to run.

Azure App Service Plan - P2V2
Azure SQL Server Plan - S4

Website is ASP Core 3.1
Using EF Core 3.1

I have researched a bit and I see that a probable cause of different query behavior from different environments may be due to parameter sniffing. Unfortunately I do not know what I can do to fix this.

Just to give some more context, I have tried recalculating the db indexes today before trying the query and I also ran `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`.

The logs for the query in question with the same parameters show this:

Azure App Service:

```
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (600,117ms) 
[Parameters=
[@__impersonateId_0='76889' (Nullable = true), 
@__impersonateId_1='76889' (Nullable = true), 
@__reportFilter_From_2='2019-01-01T00:00:00' (Nullable = true), 
@__reportFilter_To_3='2019-12-31T00:00:00' (Nullable = true), 
@__key_TransportationType_4='Rail' (Size = 450), 
@__key_CostCenter_5='' (Size = 4000)], 
CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
```

Localhost:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (11,534ms) 
[Parameters=
[@__impersonateId_0='76889' (Nullable = true), 
@__impersonateId_1='76889' (Nullable = true), 
@__reportFilter_From_2='2019-01-01T00:00:00' (Nullable = true), 
@__reportFilter_To_3='2019-12-31T00:00:00' (Nullable = true), 
@__key_TransportationType_4='Rail' (Size = 450), 
@__key_CostCenter_5='' (Size = 4000)], 
CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
```

The Stack Trace is the following:

```
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type '...'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:...
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
ClientConnectionId before routing:...
Routing Destination:...-a.worker.database.windows.net,11016
```

What can i do to research further about the reason why the query is timing out when ran from within the Azure App Service?

Comment: Can you share your query or explain what it does ?

Comment: Since parameter sniffing is just an assumption. Can you share the error message or stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT 1st of all i am not sure why anyone would downvote your answer as it did give some valuable information (no matter that i had already seen some of these). 
Sometimes i wish SO would make people give a little note on why they think a post is downvoted. Anyhow, based on your comment, i posted the stack trace.

Comment: glad you acknowledge, checking trace

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention and as seen from trace the same operation is running flawlessly on localhost but throttles on App service, it maybe that the current app service plan should be upgraded.

The timeout value can be **10 minutes** if you use a consumption based plan, or if you use premium it's unlimited. If the trigger is HTTP though then the timeout is 230 seconds regardless, this is due to the default idle [timeout](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/app-service-timeout-in-230-sec/m-p/1526934) for an Azure Load Balancer.

You could try to troubleshoot with the  [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation) or refer:  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026701/azure-long-response-time-bottleneck)  a similar issue.

Some common ways to mitigate this:

1. [Scale the web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#scale-the-web-app)
2. [Use AutoHeal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#use-autoheal)
3. [Restart the web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation#restart-the-web-app)